# Spring boot rSocket endpoints can be accessed over WebFlux port

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, rsocket, spring-rsocket

I have a spring boot server with both WebFlux controller and an rSocket controller

06-15 12:15:11.273|INFO|o.s.b.w.e.netty.NettyWebServer:111|main --- Netty started on port 8080
06-15 12:15:11.291|INFO|o.s.b.r.netty.NettyRSocketServer:65|main --- Netty RSocket started on port(s): 8081

As per the configuration, both are running on different ports.

However, I can access rSocket endpoint over WebFlux port as well.

For example, either port 8080 or 8081 connects me to rSocket.

```js
val rSocket = client.rSocket(host = window.location.hostname, port = 8080, path = "/rsocket")
```

Is this an intended behaviour?